# Wrong validation on element <br> in <ul> <li> elements

Tags: html, css, w3c-validation

I have this situation:

```
...
<ul>
  <li>Text<br/>Text</li><br />
  <li>Text<br/>Text</li>
</ul>
...
```

Looking for w3c validation I get:

> Error: Element br not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Looking next in validator I read too:

> Contexts in which element br may be used:
> Where phrasing content is expected.

So, not right if correct or not!

How I can fix this?

Comment: that snippet alone has no problems. The error is probably raised somewhere else.

Comment: The only `br` element you have in that code is a child of an `li` element not a `ul` element. It won't produce that error. You need to provide a [mcve] and make sure that it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `<li>Text<br/>Text</li><br />` The second `br` element in that line is a child of `ul`, which allows only `li` children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <ul>
>   <li>Text<br/>Text</li><br />
>   <li>Text<br/>Text</li>
> </ul>
> ```

The error message says that you can't have a `br` element as a child of a `ul` element.

You have one between the two `li` elements where it isn't allowed.

Remove it.

---

Line breaks are supposed to break a line of text and are semantically useful mostly for things like poetry where explicit line breaks are important.

List items are block elements and create line breaks automatically, there is no need to put an explicit break between them.

If you are trying to simulate a margin, then use a real margin (applied to the li element with CSS).

```css
li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text<br/>Text</li>
  <li>Text<br/>Text</li>
</ul>
```